# Performance Problems with Node.js (Mac OSX) - Processes

Tags: linux, node.js, macos, process, spawn

i hope to find some little help here.

we are using node, mongodb, supertest, mocha and spawn in our test env.

we've tried to improve our mocha test env to run tests in parallel, because our test cases run now for almost 5minutes! (600 cases)

we are spawning for example 4 processes and run tests in parallel. it is very successful, but just on linux.
on my mac the tests still run very slow. it seems like the different processes are not really running in parallel.

#### test times:

macosx:
- running 9 tests in parallel: 37s
- running 9 tests not in parallel: 41s

linux:
- running 9 tests in parallel: 16s
- running 9 tests not in parallel: 25s

#### maxosx early 2011:

10.9.2
16gb ram
core i7 2,2ghz
physical processors: 1
cores: 4
threads: 8

#### linux dell:

ubuntu
8gb ram
core i5-2520M 2.5ghz
physical processors: 1
cores: 2
threads: 4

#### my questions are:

1. are there any tips improving the process performance on macosx?
   (except of ulimit, launchctl (maxfiles)?)
2. why do the tests running much faster on linux?

thanks,
kate

Comment: Given the specs of your machines, I doubt the extra 8 gigs of ram, and processing power effect things much, especially given nodes single process model, and that you're only launching 4 processes.  I doubht for the linux machine that 8 gigs, 2.5 ghz, and 4 threads is a bottleneck at all.  As such, I would actually expect the time the processor spends running your tests to be roughly equivalent for both machines.  I'd be more interested in your Disk I/O performance, given you're running mongo.  Your Disk I/O has the most potential to slow stuff down.  What are the specs there?

Comment: macosx:  
Toshiba 5400RPM 8MB

linux:  
Seagate 7200 rpm 16mb

Comment: @ChrisCM may be on to something. http://blog.mongodb.org/post/40769806981/checking-disk-performance-with-the-mongoperf-utility may be interesting to you.

Comment: running mongoperf on both systems: macosx is much, much faster!

Comment: Mongoperf tests very specific areas of disk performance.  Looking at your specs, suggesting that your Mac drive is faster than your Linux drive is ludicrous.  You have to take mongoperf results with a grain of salt, and consider what types of disk I/O matter for your application.  Perhaps random access times aren't important, and you have a lot of sequential I/O, which the 7200 RPM drive would absolutely destroy the 5400 rpm drive in...  Remember your 5400 rpm drive is probably a laptop drive, so is much smaller, so random reads would be fast, because of the smaller disk head, but the slow

Comment: spin time, means once it finds the information, it is slow to read it. So consider your specific database... are there large chunks of information, big tables (documents in mongo), lots of entries... etc.  If so, the results from mongoperf should be ignored and replaced with common sense.

Answer (score 3):

I copied my comment here, as it describes most of the answer.

Given the specs of your machines, I doubt the extra 8 gigs of ram, and processing power effect things much, especially given nodes single process model, and that you're only launching 4 processes. I doubht for the linux machine that 8 gigs, 2.5 ghz, and 4 threads is a bottleneck at all. As such, I would actually expect the time the processor spends running your tests to be roughly equivalent for both machines. I'd be more interested in your Disk I/O performance, given you're running mongo. Your Disk I/O has the most potential to slow stuff down. What are the specs there?

Your specs: 
macosx: Toshiba 5400RPM 8MB 
linux: Seagate 7200 rpm 16mb

Your Linux drive is significantly, 1.33X faster, than your mac drive, as well as having a significantly larger cache.  For database based applications hard drive performance is crucial.  Most of the time spent in your application will be waiting for I/O, particularly in Nodes single process method of doing work.  I would suggest this as the culprit for 90% of the performance difference, and chalk the rest up to the fact that linux probably has less crap going on in the background, further exacerbating your Mac Disk Drive's performance issues.

Furthermore, launching multiple node processes isn't likely to help this.  Since processor time isn't your bottleneck, launching too many processes will just slow your disk down.  Another proof that this is the problem is that the performance of multiple processes on linux is proportionally better than the performance of multiple processes on mac.  1 process is nearly maxing out the performance of your 5400 drive, and so you don't see significant performance increase from running multiple processes.  Whereas the multiple linux Node processes use the disk to it's full potential.  You would likely see diminishing returns on the linux OS if you were to launch many more processes, unless of course you were to upgrade to a SSD.